# SQL Server, inconsistency in result of DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I'm trying to understand why the `DATEDIFF` does not work consistently.

I have a table `Projects` with below values:

```
Task_ID     Start_Date      End_Date
--------------------------------------
1           2015-10-01      2015-10-02
24          2015-10-02      2015-10-03
2           2015-10-03      2015-10-04
23          2015-10-04      2015-10-05
3           2015-10-11      2015-10-12
22          2015-10-12      2015-10-13
4           2015-10-15      2015-10-16
21          2015-10-17      2015-10-18
5           2015-10-19      2015-10-20
20          2015-10-21      2015-10-22
6           2015-10-25      2015-10-26
19          2015-10-26      2015-10-27
7           2015-10-27      2015-10-28
18          2015-10-28      2015-10-29
8           2015-10-29      2015-10-30
17          2015-10-30      2015-10-31
9           2015-11-01      2015-11-02
16          2015-11-04      2015-11-05
10          2015-11-07      2015-11-08
15          2015-11-06      2015-11-07
11          2015-11-05      2015-11-06
14          2015-11-11      2015-11-12
12          2015-11-12      2015-11-13
13          2015-11-17      2015-11-18
```

When I run the below query on it;

```
WITH t AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Start_Date s,
        End_Date e,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Start_Date) rn
    FROM 
        Projects
    GROUP BY 
        Start_Date, End_Date
)
SELECT 
    s, e, rn, DATEDIFF(day, rn, s)
FROM t
```

I get this output:

```
2015-10-01      2015-10-02      1       42275
2015-10-02      2015-10-03      2       42275
2015-10-03      2015-10-04      3       42275
2015-10-04      2015-10-05      4       42275
2015-10-11      2015-10-12      5       42281
2015-10-12      2015-10-13      6       42281
2015-10-15      2015-10-16      7       42283
2015-10-17      2015-10-18      8       42284
2015-10-19      2015-10-20      9       42285
2015-10-21      2015-10-22      10      42286
2015-10-25      2015-10-26      11      42289
2015-10-26      2015-10-27      12      42289
2015-10-27      2015-10-28      13      42289
2015-10-28      2015-10-29      14      42289
2015-10-29      2015-10-30      15      42289
2015-10-30      2015-10-31      16      42289
2015-11-01      2015-11-02      17      42290
2015-11-04      2015-11-05      18      42292
2015-11-05      2015-11-06      19      42292
2015-11-06      2015-11-07      20      42292
2015-11-07      2015-11-08      21      42292
2015-11-11      2015-11-12      22      42295
2015-11-12      2015-11-13      23      42295
2015-11-17      2015-11-18      24      42299
```

But when I individually execute `DATEDIFF`, I get different results:

```
select DATEDIFF(day, 1, 2015-10-01)
```

2003

```
select DATEDIFF(day, 2, 2015-10-02)
```

2001

Can someone please explain this to me? Am I doing something wrong with the individual select statement?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Set up a dbfiddle which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Prashy, datediff function takes 2 dates instead of day number

Comment: And `2015-10-02` is very different from `'2015-10-02'`.

Comment: 2015-10-01 = 2004. You have to write `select DATEDIFF(day, 1, '2015-10-01')`

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Thanks a lot. Now I get it. After I added the quotes its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the arguments for datediff look like.

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

Judging by the parameters you passed, I assume you are trying to substract 1 or 2 days from a date. You should use

```
DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
```

So substracting just becomes adding with a minus like `DATEADD (day,-1,'2015-10-02')`

If you really wanted to use the `DATEDIFF` function as intended, make sure you use single quotes around your dates and read the datepart boundaries section in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), because a nanosecond difference at the boundary can turn into a year difference in your result.

Also when using a number X as a date, SQL Server interprets it as (1900-01-01 + X days).